# What information is shown to owner of a wishlist from a buyer

Tags: amazon, wish-list

I was asked to purchase an item on an Amazon wishlist. 
My question is what information is shown to the receiver? 
Will they know who it is from? Will it display my name and address?

Answer (score 1):

> Will they know who it is from? Will it display my name and address?

No, items purchased & shipped from wishlist will be anonymous - you can choose to add a note though

Answer (score -1):

Just FYI - I found a way around this when I wanted to see who sent me a gift.. Amazon most of the time will include a note that says "Send a personalized thank you note" and if they go to that link (Or scan QR code) the note will come up that says "Hi *your name* thank you for the gift" or something like that.. so they will be able to tell that it was from you if they know to do that.  :)